# Program Runs Fine for Hours and Eventually Seg Faults with Memory Address 0x10

Tags: c++, c, memory, arm

So I've been tracking some memory issue for the longest time. I'm coding in C++ and I can see that my program mostly works. I am monitoring my resources and I dont think I have a memory leak because my memory used stays below 12% (I'm on a system with 256MB memory). I can let this thing run for hours and it works but eventually it segfaults.

It is hard to anaylize this issue because it takes so long for an issue to actually come up. It just crashed after running it in a debugger all day and I can see that I am doing some work on what should be a valid pointer address.

```
  sprintf(asciihex, "%x", var[c] & MASK);  //Where var is a pointer
                                           //MASK is 0xff
```

I know this works because my program runs with valid info for hours, but when the program crashes, instead of my var being a valid pointer **(0xbb6b03408)**, the memory address is **(0x10)**.

Also other variables (it is part of a struct) are actually NULLed. So I am trying to figure out what is going on here. My code has a check for NULL pointers and skips over them but 0x10 isn't considered NULL so it breaks. I've seen other values like 0x15 and 0x18 so I dont want to just add more checks for those, I want to find the root cause.

Any suggestions would be great!

Comment: You have a bug in your code. I suggest you find it and fix it.

Comment: It could be anything. Maybe you're zeroing-out the stack somewhere; maybe you just have an error condition that you don't check for. How could we know if you don't?

Comment: Sorry but anything we give you would be a guess. I doubt anyone can diagnose your problem from 2 lines of code.

Comment: Nothing specific related to [tag:eclipse-cdt], removed.

Comment: Another possibility (in addition to what Zan Lynx mentioned) is that you have a buffer overflow somewhere. (the use of `sprintf` without length-limited specifiers is a bit scary...)

Comment: Does the program continuously allocate and free memory, and does the program run with paged (virtual) memory? If so, there could be a fragmentation issue, where the pages end up with unusable empty gaps, and eventually the program runs out of pages and/or virtual address space. Something like Microsoft's .NET framework avoids this by occasionally repacking pages (while pausing a program in order to do this).

Comment: Is there a way to enable a trace on the pointer var, so that when the crash occurs, you can view the last write that was done to var?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I predict that your struct is being dynamically allocated via `new` or `malloc` and someone is either eating the `std::bad_alloc` exception without handling it or ignoring a NULL return.

An address of 0x10 is almost certainly NULL plus the struct member offset. That would also explain the zeroed fields because most operating systems map a virtual zero page at NULL.

To add onto this, if the code is being compiled without C++ exception handling, I often see it doesn't expect NULL returns from `new` calls. That's because normally a failed memory allocation would throw the exception instead of returning a value.

You can't just turn off exception handling in the compiler without fixing the code as well.

Comment: To test this theory I'd suggest adding a test into the code by having an allocation fail on demand and see what happens

Comment: Indeed, "run for hours" in particular flags up the possibility of allocations eventually failing unexpectedly due to heap fragmentation.

Comment: I've marked this as an answer because it helped direct me into where to look. Particularly your second paragraph. I am still trying to understand how this can happen but this makes the most sense and I think I might have trapped the affected area, but I now need to figure out why this happens